# Make @ExceptionHandler handle every exception except AccessDeniedException?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, exception

I wrote an `@ExceptionHandler` to send the exception in JSON for REST requests. However, due to the way Spring Security works, `AccessDeniedException`s must not be handled.

If I simply rethrow an `AccessDeniedException` in the handler, I get an `ERROR` level logging saying:

```
Failed to invoke @ExceptionHandler method: SomeMethod() throws java.lang.Exception
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
...Stack...
```

I cannot safely disable `ERROR` level logging for the class logging it (`ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver`), but having these stacktrace is quite confusing for operations people.

Is there anyway to make `@ExceptionHandler` not handle this specific exception?

Comment: You can add custom generic excepton superclass and extend all your exception from it. And catch them with your ExceptionHandler.

Comment: @IlyaDyoshin Unfortunately, my application throws about 3 custom exceptions in total. Most of the exceptions are throwns by frameworks which I would rather not wrap.

Comment: Issue raised: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13932 May get fixed in Spring 5.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could just use global exception handler instead, so you don't manually handle this `AccessDeniedExceptions`, 
this global exception will be thrown for every kinds of exceptions (except for the exception handlers that you handle manually):

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public ModelAndView handleException() {
        return new ModelAndView("errorGlobal");
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what I had and exactly what the question asks to avoid. The class that handles `@ExceptionHandler` will log that log that I do not want...